# Form submit using AJAX is not working

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

PHP/Ajax newbie here...I am trying to save the contents of a textarea into MySQL via Ajax. Although the data IS being saved correctly, Ajax isn't quite working. Basically, the page is "reloaded/refreshed" after the data is saved, unlike Ajax. Can you please tell me what is that I am doing wrong?

index.html:

```
<form action="save.php" method="post" id="source-form">
<span><input type="submit" value="Save" /></span>
<div>
<textarea id="editor" name="editor" >

</textarea>
</div>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#source-form").submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"save.php",
        type:"post",
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        success: alert('saved');
    });
});
```

save.php

```
<?php

// connect to the database
include('connect-db.php'); 

// get form data, making sure it is valid
$submit_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$content = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['editor']));

//build query
mysql_query("INSERT source SET submit_date='$submit_date',content='$content'")
or die(mysql_error());

header('Location: index.html');

?>
```

Any help on this is appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT:** 
For folks running into the same issue or something similar...here's a great solution from:
http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started

Comment: Use http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Answer (score 1):

change your `<form action="save.php" method="post" id="source-form">`

to `<form  method="post" id="source-form">`

remove the action you already declared your url in the ajax

remove `header('Location: index.html');` since your should not redirect since your are using ajax. remember that if you are using ajax you dont need to refresh the page just let it receive a confirmation that the result was successful

Answer (score 0):

Add a `return false;` to forum submit so that the form submit is cancelled:

```
$("#source-form").submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"save.php",
        type:"post",
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        success: alert('saved');
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you define _not working_ ? Does the form still get submitted (refreshed)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop the default behavior of the submit button (form posting).Otherwise the form will be submitted again and you will see the page loading again. You use the [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) function

```
$("#source-form").submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
        url:"save.php",
        type:"post",
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        success: alert('saved');
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only using the form for a ajax submit, I would suggest removing the form from the HTML completely and using a click event.  I've stripped things down to a minimum in the HTML:

**HTML**

```
<input id="save-text" type="submit" value="Save" />
<textarea id="editor" name="editor" ></textarea>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#save-text").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"save.php",
        type:"post",
        data: $("#editor").serialize(),
        success: alert('saved');
    });
});
```

Comment: Also, have you tried removing 'header('Location: index.html');' from the end of your php file?

Comment: Have you tried in different browsers?  If you've removed the form element from the HTML and are only using the two lines I've put above,  is it possible some other javascript is acting on it?

Comment: i noticed something new using Firefox. The page is not refreshing...but the data is now not being saved.